# How to declare the return type of a generic arrow function to be an array and value at the same time in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Consider a function which takes an array, property name and an arrow function as arguments. What I want to achieve is, filter the array and overwrite the mentioned property's value with an array (output of the arrow function) based on the length check.

```
overwriteFieldWith<T1, T2 extends T1[keyof T1]>(
      input: Array<T1>, property: keyof T1, onOverwrite: (i: T1) => T2
): T[] {
   // filter the input array and replace the property for
   // each item with the output of the supplied arrow function
   return input.filter(i => {
       const value = onOverwrite(i);
       if(value.length) {  // giving me error 'length does not exist on type T2'
          i[property] = value;
          console.log(i);
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
   });
}
```

It gives me error when I try to do length check on it. The supplied arrow function is always going to return an array but how can I satisfy the compiler on this?

Edit:
[Link](https://tsplay.dev/NdYBYm) to the ts playground.

Comment: Can't understand it fully! Could you please upload your local script here (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and share the full link (with updated hash)?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that we can paste as-is into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue and only your issue.  Right now I don't know what `T` is, and it would be nice to see input/output examples since it's not obvious from your code that `T2` really is always an array type.

Comment: Once you've done that: does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wERovN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: I have added an example for the problem I'm looking into it. (I didn't have the whole code in my local). Thank you so much for looking into it :) @SanthoshJohn

Comment: @jcalz, T2 is not an array all the time. But the actual logic is only intended when T2 is an array. There can be properties other than array in T1. Please fine the playground link, sorry for missing that out earlier.

Comment: Thanks.  So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7y7oW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, etc blah blah same as before @jcalz etc

Comment: @jcalz, Yes, this approach meets my need. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
overwriteFieldWith<T, K extends keyof T>(
    input: Array<T>,
    property: K,
    onOverwrite: (i: T) => Extract<T[K], readonly any[]>
): T[] {
    return input.filter(i => {
        const value = onOverwrite(i);
        if (value.length) {
            i[property] = value;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I made the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `property`, so that the type checker keeps track of *which* property we're talking about.  That way we can require that `onOverWrite()` actually return something assignable to *that* property value instead of something else... we need to know this or else `i[property] = value` might be unsafe.

I also made the return type of `onOverwrite()` just `Extract<T[K], readonly any[]>` using [the `Extract<T, U>` union filtering utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) instead of some generic `U extends T[K]`.

(Note that [the `readonly any[]` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) is wider than just `any[]`; we don't care about modifying the array so we don't need to require mutable methods to exist).

This serves the purpose of convincing the compiler that `value.length` will exist (since the compiler accepts that `Extract<T, U>` is assignable to both `T` and `U`, so the compiler knows that `value` is an `readonly any[]`).  It also serves the purpose of requiring that `onOverwrite()` return only those union members of the property type `T[K]` that are arrays.  This works for your example use case at any rate.

---

Let's test it:

```
const filtered = a.overwriteFieldWith(elementTypes, 'elements', (i) =>
    i?.elements?.filter(data => !data.hide) ?? []);
/* (method) A.overwriteFieldWith<ElementType, "elements">(input: ElementType[], 
   property: "elements", onOverwrite: (i: ElementType) => TElement[]
): ElementType[] */
```

Looks good.  Note that the compiler inferred `T` as `ElementType` and `K` as `"elements"`, and thus that the return type of `onOverwrite()` is `TElment[]` as demonstrated here:

```
type TK = ElementType['elements'];
//type TK = TElement[] | undefined

type XTK = Extract<ElementType['elements'], readonly any[]>
// type XTK = TElement[]
```

So an `ElementType` might have an undefined `elements` property, but `onOverwrite` cannot return `undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=24&pln=7&pc=18#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoFEA2EC2FzIDeAUMmcggPbj5gBcyAzmFKAOYDcp5AFsACYQGAI0qVscEFwC+xYqEixEKLLlqoAngAcUJcsjDahTFuy76I2POEYB+BgEEoUOBoA8GK7QB8xWcQRMOEZGZAcibjJKADdoAHdWSAAxYEt+AHVgMB4PABpkAGlkCAAPSBB+UIBrCA1KGDRvAApI-WRQLQBXejDnVw9vXNb9LShKHShDBgKhtvJqAHlYqASs4ybgBlQASmQAXm9kdDKXBDAPAG0CgF18qAg4fmpMDWRJDQvr331trc+IuZke5gTpQEDtEBdMAAOhgwEwig2+0OekB+ioIGYyGicEwnRQe2Qi2Wq0gG225jR5GADSaOLxEGh2BAbGyu1RVLawAuo3G0EM1322Nx+MpnP0wNB4JYouGgOkxUwjF0cs5krByHgSogYqpsjR0gprVk-gxWMsanAABE4GA4AsQMYnC53J5LWBDoSLq1CBRqOUegByfi2uAAWmoEED+T4ggYWuVyGks3IvoxAYYwdDYbAcUo0eQseMMpQyZ9fpo4EzIbtOZ49yjMYExag+KTKbIaf9tGr2ZglFBBaL8dxidk1y4AWo5q81tDqDzjj6rtU1g9Qu9+i7laDNfDkaHzYYJfb5fTPeQWdrufzTbjBlbpaGE7kZrAivdNrtqHrECdy48VcfA3F8p0xd8LTXTQdEYJcXTcIDwGgiBPWQTdUwMIxMwcAtINoWCPzXL97UdU8t0wnRMwAIVw2cwAIvC52-PMyIwwxKMvABhWj3QYujiJ-BtWM7CjjEDbj8kY+iGE6CoIDhR1+FPUC3zeIVHTiMImiNMCsThBFoAgJTCTgaEYniRIIBSNJMmyJopOQxh8kDKTGALclkVaYBbGhVyfP0xE92RZAAEI92hItdlsWw0OuI0AHoACpkCaPBskofhdgcMySUs6zMAyLIckQsBkPyAAiVzyuaDpugYErkM+fJIl5CYpmQSq6MYcr8mJCy1gYDZ6ro5DdgONASs+YhfiOEajH+RL4rkdiUFQIpCQa+aXK6wMX3i+KVrQdaJro-4AB9kFkwQFKM4hDoADTWoVjhYRBzk2nQLm23jdruB4nhAF43hAD4vmIfbROQR7jrdNcpt08RGUwSg2CaALDMyjhkAh9H7iUyMEewJkUfsuaYIpbH4reM5OlxIlHWIIA)